# Sending a confirmation email after a google form is submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have looked at many resources to figure out what is wrong with my script but nothing is working.  I am trying to send a confirmation email after a google form has been submitted.  It seems like my script is not calling the email address correctly from the form.
My original script came from http://acrl.ala.org/techconnect/?p=2343 and I modified it for my form.
This is what it looked like:

```
function swykemailconfirm(e) {
  var userEmail = e.values[10]; //email from column K
  var firstName = e.values[2]; //first name from column C
  var lastName = e.values[1]; //last name from column B
  var test = e.values[4]; //test name from column E
 MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, 
                    "Thank you " +firstName + lastName + "for signing up to take the " + test + "Show What You Know test. " + 
                    "Make sure you see Ms. May to get your pass. " +
                    "See you on Thursday in room 32 at 3:30." +
                    "The Math Department");
}
```

I am getting an email with this error message after doing a test form submission:
Can not find method (class) sendEmail (string, string). (Line 6, file "Code")

After searching here [Google Forms Confirmation Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256019/google-forms-confirmation-script) for a way to edit my script, I used one of the suggestions and changed my code to the following:

```
function swykemailconfirm(e) {
  var userEmail = e.values["E-mail"][0];
  var firstName = e.values[2];
  var lastName = e.values[1];
  var test = e.values[4];
 MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, 
                    "Thank you " +firstName + lastName + "for signing up to take the " + test + "Show What You Know test. " + 
                    "Make sure you see Ms. May to get your pass. " +
                    "See you on Thursday in room 32 at 3:30." +
                    "The Math Department");
}
```

I am getting an email with this error message after doing a test form submission:
TypeError: Can not read property "0" from undefined. (Line 2, file "Code")

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your original function (top) will work properly with one small modification.

Google Docs is giving you the error message "Cannot find method (class) sendEmail (string, string). (Line 6, file "Code")" because the sendEmail method requires three arguments to passed: recipient (string), subject (string), body (string). Currently, you are only passing two arguments: recipient and body. See documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)

Modify your function to the following and everything should work!

```
function swykemailconfirm(e) {
  var userEmail = e.values[10]; //email from column K
  var firstName = e.values[2]; //first name from column C
  var lastName = e.values[1]; //last name from column B
  var test = e.values[4]; //test name from column E
  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, 
      "Registration Confirmation Subject Line",
      "Thank you " +firstName + lastName + "for signing up to take the " + test + "Show What You Know test. " + 
      "Make sure you see Ms. May to get your pass. " +
      "See you on Thursday in room 32 at 3:30." +
      "The Math Department");
}
```

Hope that helps!